# Reference anonymous object from within a nested anonymous class

Tags: java, this, anonymous-class

Is it possible to do something like this (I use initializer blocks to shorten the example)

```
new A() {{
  new B() {{
    method(outer.this);
  }}
}}
```

Where I supply the this of the outer object as a parameter to the method call within the second anonymous class? I cannot use A.this, this gives a compile error.

Note: the given code does not compile, it should only illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Edit: example that lies closer to the actual use case:

```
public class Outer {

  public SomeBean createBean() {
    return new SomeBean() {

      private final Object reference = new SomeClass() {

        @Override
        public void notify() {
          Outer.callback(/*what goes here???*/);
        }
      };

      //Methods...
    };
  }

  public static void callback(final SomeBean bean) {
    // do stuff with bean
  }
}
```

And the compile error I get is just that I'm not providing the correct argument to callback, as I don't know how to reference the SomeBean subclass...

Comment: does it work when you put the code inside a method? Inside the initializers you are trying to reference an object which isn't created yet.

Comment: The answer depends on your actual usecase.

Comment: I don't recommend unsafe publication of `this`. Also, can you please show us the compiler error?

Comment: I elaborated the problem a bit more in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really must*, I guess this should work.

```
new A() {
    {
        new B() {{
            method();
        }};
    }
    private void method() {
        method(this);
    }
}
```

(Historical note: With `-target 1.3` or earlier, this should NPE.)

If you don't need the exact type of the `A` inner class.

```
new A() {
    {
        new B() {{
            method(a);
        }};
    }
    private A a() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion is along the lines of what I've currently done, it works, but I was wondering whether it is possible to directly call the needed method instead of providing a "proxy-method", I'll keep this solution if the direct call isn't possible though.

Comment: I'll accept this one as it is the solution I also came up with myself and I don't think there really is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

@TomHawtin 's answer is good, mine is quite similar. I would do this:

```
new A() {
    private final A anon = this;
    /*init*/ {
        new B() {
            /*init*/ {
                method(anon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<del>This will probably give you *slightly* better performance than calling a method to get your A instance.</del> The main benefit is IMO this is easier to read/maintain.

Edit:
@Tomas 's answer is also very similar, but required that you keep a reference to your new A object in the outer-outer class, where it might not be needed.

In light of op's edit:

```
public SomeBean createBean() {
    SomeBean myBean = new SomeBean() {
        private final Object reference = new SomeClass() {
            @Override
            public void notify() {
                Outer.callback(/*what goes here???*/);
            }
        };
        //Methods...
    };
    return myBean;
}
```

FYI obj.notify() is a final method in Object, you can't override it. JavaDoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your comment. / The field solution is slightly more concise, although it does add an extra field, probably giving *slightly* worse performance. I think the private field will cause a synthetic accessor method to be generated.

Comment: I can't claim any intimate knowledge of the compiler, I was under the impression that field-access was slightly faster than trivial method invokation. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: notify was just an example name, I didn't think of the method in Object while typing it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring your code, as the code you are proposing doesn't seem too logical, and for sure not easy to handle or mantain.
You could do a pretty similar structure (subclassing two different types and using one from another) with something like this:

```
//declaring a variable as final enables accessing it from the B subtype if declared at the same scope (method)
final A myA=new A() {
   //personalized content for type A
};
//then, declare the B subtype, using the final myA var as you need, at the constructor 
B myB=new B() {{
   method(myA);
}};
```

This, in case you need to overwrtie both classes, as you exposed. Maybe a little rethink could save you from these anonymous classes (or at least, from some of them).